# Prevent automatic redirects in Mobile Firefox for Android

Tags: firefox-for-android

How can I turn disable redirects in Firefox for Android?

Here is a solution that works for desktop Firefox:

[Prevent automatic redirects in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/874819/prevent-automatic-redirects-in-firefox)

Unfortunately the **accessibility.blockautorefresh** option is not present in Firefox for Android.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1468137/855367) from the same question you linked, you can use `network.http.redirection-limit` to block redirects. Start by setting it to `0` (instead of `1` as in the linked answer). It will will have the effects of blocking all redirects and even accessing any site.

Then increasing with the value will allow depending on the site to allow redirects (or clicking "Try again" when the redict was blocked).

Comment: OP is asking for Android